# Powershell containskey logic failing Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell

I'm not sure where my logic is off? The idea behind this script is to locate all of our admin accounts that are associated with a disabled user account. We use codes for SamAccountName, but the admin accounts end with -a, -d, -e for our IT admins. I thought if I looked at all the disabled users and created and array, then grabbed all the enabled admin accounts, then did a lookup where the first 9 numbers matched, I would get a list back with disabled users who had an enabled admin account. Instead, I get matches on both accounts disabled and only via Excel can I see the ones that have an associated enabled admin account. Why is my method not working as I intend? Thx

```
$Users1 = Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $False} -Properties SamAccountName, name, title, enabled,lastlogondate,accountexpirationdate | select SamAccountName, name, title,enabled,lastlogondate, accountexpirationdate
$Users2 = Get-ADUser -Filter {samaccountname -like "*-a" -or samaccountname -like "*-d" -or samaccountname -like "*-e" -and enabled -eq $True} -Properties SamAccountName, name, title,enabled, lastlogondate,accountexpirationdate | select SamAccountName, name,enabled, title,lastlogondate, accountexpirationdate
$output = "C:\scripts\adcleanup\Admin-Accounts-Need-Term_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv"
$SIDTable = @{}

$Users1 | ForEach-Object {

    $SIDTable[$_.SamAccountName] = $_
}

$matching = ForEach ($User in $Users2) {

    $SID = $User.SamAccountName.Substring(0,8)

     If ($SIDTable.containskey($SID)) {

     $SIDTable[$SID] | Select @{Name="SID";Expression={$user.SamAccountName}},SamAccountName,@{Name="Admin Enabled";Expression={$user.enabled}},"Enabled","Name", "Title", "LastLogonDate", "AccountExpirationDate"

     }}
     $matching | Export-csv $output -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: `$string = Substring(0,8)` will give you the first **8** characters of `$string`. Unless you are absolutely sure that the samaccountname is *always* 8 or 9 characters, you'd rather want to remove the last `-a` (or `-d`/`-e`): `$string.Remove($string.IndexOf('-'))`

Comment: I guess that's why I'm confused. I know the length of our SamAccountNames are always 9 characters long, so I thought I'd get the correct list. Even with the indexOf as you say, how can I get containskey on both disabled accounts when one array should have only disabled and the other only disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you group the clauses in the `Filter` correctly:

```
-Filter {(samaccountname -like "*-a" -or samaccountname -like "*-d" -or samaccountname -like "*-e") -and enabled -eq $True}
```